# How to add methods dynamically to Vue component

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

When I get data from the server, like 
`[{methodName:mothodValue},{methodName:mothodValue}]`
then I want dynamic generation method, like

```
methods: {
  functionArray.forEach(function (item) {
    item.functionName:function () {
      item.functionValue;
    }
  })
}
```

so this is my code

```
var componentName = Vue.component(componentName, {
  data: function () {
    return {
      value: value
    }
  },
  template: componentTemplate,
  methods:{
    functionArray.forEach(function (item) {
      item.functionName:function () {
        item.functionValue;
      }
    })
  }
})
```

the old code was

```
methods:{
  getValue : function(){
    getValue(this.value);
  }
}
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data from the server is returned before the creation of the Vue component (I'm not sure if you can add methods after the creation of a Vue component), then you can create a methods object like so:

```
var methods = {};
functionArray.forEach(function (item) {
  methods[item.functionName] = item.functionValue;
});
```

You can't populate an object literal with code, but you can populate an empty object literal afterwards with code like so.

---

Then you can put it into your component like so:

```
var componentName = Vue.component(componentName, {
  // ..
  methods: methods
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer,I have finished